# Build comprehensive formula for all precedent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to build a comprehensive formula for all precedent cells?  I'm aware and employ the "Trace Precedents" and "Trace Dependents" feature in Excel often, but this only goes back one "layer" in the precedent tree, only provides graphical feedback, and requires manual intervention to continue back in the tree.

Suppose:

```
A1 = 3
A2 = 2
A3 = (A1 * A2)
A4 = 6
A5 = A3 + A4
A6 = A5 ^ 2
```

I am looking for the ability to highlight A6 and select "Obtain All Precedents" such the result is:

```
((A1 * A2) + A4) ^ 2
```

The recursion stops (and uses the cell reference) when the substitution is a constant and not dependent on any other cells.  I find [one other question](https://superuser.com/questions/774090/expanding-a-cell-formula-resolving-all-its-references-precedents) on Superuser that deals with this topic, but requesting something slightly different (reducing the recursion to constants).  I'm looking for the "super formula" for all precedent cells, not the constants by substitution.

Comment: [Check this out](http://superuser.com/a/384782/116196)